# System of linear equation question.

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the system of linear equations in real variables $x, y, z$

a) Solve (E): $x-2y+z=17$ and $4x+y+z=14$

b) (F): $x-2y+z=17$ and $4x+y+z=14$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2=a$, where $a$ is a real constant

Suppose (F) has unique solutions. 
Find $a$ and solve (F)

I have solved (E), the answer is $x=5-3t,y=1/3t-6, z=t$, where $t$ is a real number.

But I have no idea how to tackle b) of the questions.

How to solve b), Thanks

Answer (score 1):

solving b) is similar to a).  first solve two linear equations $x-2y=17-t$ , $4x+y=14-t$ to get the parametric form as you mentioned above:
$$x=5-\frac{1}{3}t \\ y=\frac{1}{3}t-6 \\ z=t$$
now substitute three variables $x,y,z$ in the last equation to get an equation in terms of $t$. then solve for $t$ and substitute $t$ to get $x,y,z$ as follows:
$$(5-\frac{1}{3}t)^2+(\frac{1}{3}t-6)^2+t^2=a \Rightarrow 11t^2-66t+549-9a=0$$
by solving for t we get two answers:
$$t=\frac{66 \pm \sqrt{(66)^2-4(11)(549-9a)}}{22}$$
as mentioned in question b), (F) must have a unique solution. so there must be a root of order 2. in other words square root must be zero:
$$(66)^2-4(11)(549-9a)=0 \Rightarrow 99-549=-9a \Rightarrow a=\frac{450}{9}=50$$
which gives the unique solution $t=3 \Rightarrow (x=4,y=-5,z=3)$ which means two planes are tangent to sphere in mentioned point.

Comment: Ok. thanks for feedback.

Comment: pffff my bad dude. you're right. thanks again